# Filter query result based on earliest date for subset of query

Tags: sql, t-sql, filter, ssms, partition

I've constructed a query that will return a table as such:

```
| NAME   | DATE   |
| Item 1 | Date 1 |
| Item 1 | Date 2 |
| Item 1 | Date 3 |
| Item 2 | Date 1 |
| Item 2 | Date 2 |
| Item 3 | Date 1 |
| Item 3 | Date 2 |
| Item 3 | Date 3 |
| Item 3 | Date 4 |
```

Basically a one-to-many grouping. I'd like to filter out from this result set the rows with the earliest date on a per-item basis. Meaning, for each item remove the row with the highest date (Remove 'Date 1' for each 'Item'). How can I return this query with the "Date 1" rows removed?

Ex output:

```
| NAME   | DATE   |
| Item 1 | Date 2 |
| Item 1 | Date 3 |
| Item 2 | Date 2 |
| Item 3 | Date 1 |
| Item 3 | Date 3 |
| Item 3 | Date 4 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Date])
   FROM (...Your query here...) T
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1;
```